# Python tegram bot как переслать сообщение из другого канала teleram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
telebot.TeleBot = ('API')     
@bot.message_handler(commands=['news'])
```

Как заставить эту команду пересылать последнее сообщение, например, из telegram канала "news",  в личные сообщения

> Private messages (bot-me)
>
> ^
>
> |
>
> telegram-chanel "news"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
chat_id = int(#Чат айди куда будут пересылаться сообщенния)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['news'])
def Receiving_a_message(message):
    ids = message.message_id - 1
    bot.forward_message(chat_id, message.chat.id, ids)
```

Попробуй у меня вышло так